# Safely cast strings to ints in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples like so:

```
[('1001794', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '1', '3', '4', '5')
('1001832', 'Us/Central', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5')
('1001848', 'Us/Central', '2', '4', '5', '4', '5')
('1001855', 'Us/Central', '2', '1', '4', '4', '5')
('1001899', 'Us/Central', '2', '1', '4', '3', '5')
('1001914', 'Us/Pacific', '1', '4', '2', '4', '5')
('1001971', 'Us/Pacific', '3', '4', '2', '3', '5')
('1002021', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '1', '4', '4', '5')
('1002026', 'Us/Central', '2', '1', '4', '4', '2')
('1002028', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '1', '4', '4', '5')
('1002041', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '4', '3', '5', '4')]
```

And I need to convert all the numbers in there to numbers. I don't mind if I have to do 6 different list comprehensions if necessary, but I still can't wrap my head around list comprehension enough to make one from scratch properly. I tried doing:

```
[x = (int(x[0]),x[1],int(x[2]),int(x[3]),int(x[4]),int(x[5]),int(x[6])) for x in tlist]
```

But it tells me it's invalid syntax, and I'm not sure why?

Comment: Because you're doing an assignment in the list comprehension. Get rid of `x =`.

Comment: and I assume that's not allowed? So list comprehension is not the tool for this then? I don't just want to see them in that format, I want the list to have them in that format

Comment: I edited my comment. But the "I'll do 6 comprehensions" doesn't make sense; they are not sufficiently faster than regular `for` loops to justify this kind of approach; don't pursue list comprehensions at the vast expense of sensible code

Comment: No, list comprehensions are perfectly fine for this. But there are no assignment statements in list comprehensions, only expressions are allowed. If you are thikning in terms of assignment, i.e. mutating state, then you shouldn't use list-comprehensions, and just use a regular for loop. But this *could* be a very straightforward list comprehension, no doubt

Comment: okay I'll just do a for loop then, thanks

Comment: Why? Youve already been given a working answer.

Comment: Oh when I wrote that comment the answers hadn't shown up yet :P I will take one of them now lol. Also juanpa's comment hadn't loaded either, so I'd only seen the above ones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.isdigit`:

```
[tuple(int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in x) for x in tup]
# [(1001794, 'Us/Eastern', 2, 1, 3, 4, 5), ...]
```

This is assuming the numbers in your strings are integers. `tup` is your data structure.

---

To handle negative integers, use a function encapsulating a `try-except` block (read about the [EAFP principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)):

```
def try_convert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

[tuple(try_convert(y) for y in x) for x in tup]
# [(1001794, 'Us/Eastern', 2, 1, 3, 4, 5), ...]
```

To handle `int`s and `float`s, you may use a nested block:

```
def try_convert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return s
```

Comment: I like this answer. Thanks for pointing out the usefulness of `isdigit`.

Comment: Not a bad approach, provided all of the numbery-looking strings look like positive integers. "-2" will remain a string, for example.

Comment: I'll give it to this one bc it's a good general solution in case anyone else has a similar problem

Comment: I would say `isdigit` is not good here. Rather, encapsulate your `may_int` in a function, that uses `try: return int(obj) except ValueError: return obj`. Or just hard-code it. Tuples *should* be regular.

Comment: @Kevin Fixed, ty

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
y = [('1001794', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '1', '3', '4', '5'),
     ('1002041', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '4', '3', '5', '4')]
x = [(int(x[0]),x[1],int(x[2]),int(x[3]),int(x[4]),int(x[5]),int(x[6])) for x in y]
print(x)
[(1001794, 'Us/Eastern', 2, 1, 3, 4, 5), (1002041, 'Us/Eastern', 2, 4, 3, 5, 4)]
```

You just need the `x =` outside the `[`.

Comment: Yep, `tlist = [(int(x[0]),x[1],int(x[2]),int(x[3]),int(x[4]),int(x[5]),int(x[6])) for x in tlist]` works for me.

Comment: This works but hardcodes everything, including the position of the string that should not be converted.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where the `ints` are, you can use [`Extended Iterable Unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to simplify the list comprehension you where trying to use:

```
[(int(x), y, *map(int,v)) for x, y, *v in l]

[(1001794, 'Us/Eastern', 2, 1, 3, 4, 5),
 (1001832, 'Us/Central', 2, 3, 4, 4, 5),
 (1001848, 'Us/Central', 2, 4, 5, 4, 5),
 (1001855, 'Us/Central', 2, 1, 4, 4, 5),
 (1001899, 'Us/Central', 2, 1, 4, 3, 5),
 (1001914, 'Us/Pacific', 1, 4, 2, 4, 5),
 (1001971, 'Us/Pacific', 3, 4, 2, 3, 5),
 (1002021, 'Us/Eastern', 2, 1, 4, 4, 5),
 (1002026, 'Us/Central', 2, 1, 4, 4, 2),
 (1002028, 'Us/Eastern', 2, 1, 4, 4, 5),
 (1002041, 'Us/Eastern', 2, 4, 3, 5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

is this the Answer your looking of ?

```
list = []
newList = []

list = [
        ('1001794', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '1', '3', '4', '5'),
        ('1001832', 'Us/Central', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5'),
        ('1001848', 'Us/Central', '2', '4', '5', '4', '5'),
        ('1001855', 'Us/Central', '2', '1', '4', '4', '5'),
        ('1001899', 'Us/Central', '2', '1', '4', '3', '5'),
        ('1001914', 'Us/Pacific', '1', '4', '2', '4', '5'),
        ('1001971', 'Us/Pacific', '3', '4', '2', '3', '5'),
        ('1002021', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '1', '4', '4', '5'),
        ('1002026', 'Us/Central', '2', '1', '4', '4', '2'),
        ('1002028', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '1', '4', '4', '5'),
        ('1002041', 'Us/Eastern', '2', '4', '3', '5', '4')
        ]

newList = [[int(x[0]), x[1], int(x[2]), int(x[3]), int(x[4]), int(x[5]), int(x[6])] for x in list]

print(newList)
```